# Codeigniter auto change the input field value

Tags: codeigniter, input

when i give an input field value as blackhat%%1985 and submit i get the post value as blackhat%85
the value is changed after require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

```
<form action="" method="post" id="submitForm">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="blackhat%%1985" />
<input type="submit" name="b" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you encode the value (`blackhat%25%251985`)?

Comment: @Shomz here user submit their password.. how to encode before submittion?

Comment: You can use JavaScript's encodeURIComponent to change the value before submitting the form. `encodeURIComponent('blackhat%%1985');`

Answer (score 1):

use urlencode() function for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's encodeURIComponent to encode the value before submitting the form.

`encodeURIComponent('blackhat%%1985');`

Of course, don't forget to decode it on the server-side after that.